# the convolution of integrable functions is continuous?

Tags: harmonic-analysis, continuity

The question is simple but I still can't prove it or contradict it. Here it goes:

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are defined on the circle
>   (or, equivalently, $2\pi$ periodic functions) and Lebesgue integrable, 
>   is their convolution $(f*g)(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x-y) g(y) dy $ continuous?

In the case when two functions are bounded, it is proved in Elias Stein's 
*Fourier Analysis* (page 47) that their convolution **is** truly continuous.
However, for unbounded functions, I have tried tools in real analysis, say, Lusin's theorem, transition continuity of $L_1$ functions, etc., but can't figure it out.

Comment: Let me remark that it is sufficient that one of the functions is bounded (the convolution of an $L^1$-function and an $L^\infty$-function on a unimodular group is always continuous.

Comment: yes, you are right, a similar proof from the book will do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Edit: sorry, there was a sign error.  It should just be:

$$f(x) = g(x) = \begin{cases}
x^{-3/4}&x > 0\cr
0&x \leq 0.
\end{cases}$$
Then $\lim_{x \to 0^+}f*g(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^-} f*g(x) = 0$.

Comment: Are you sure you have calculated the integrals ? I computed the two integrals in mathematica $f*g(x)$ with $x=10^{-7}$ and $x=-10^{-7}$, both going very large.

Comment: No. The overlap is nearly half the interval. Say, for $x=-0.0001$, the overlap is $[-\pi+0.0001,-0.0001]$

Comment: @booksee Does it matter? If it goes to infinity the convolution is certainly not in $C(\mathbb{T})$ (it is for the real-line, but that does not really change the game, the large values of $x$ are irrelevant). The example is kinda standard, you could look [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm12/sm1213.pdf), I think you can trust in it.

Comment: In this example, $f*g(0)=\infty$, which to some extent really solves my question. I have never imagined that the counterexample will look like this-_-.

Comment: Oops, the remark in parentheses is a remark to my second sentence.

Comment: @TheUser, the paper you refer to seems not talk about convolution, since $ab(t)=\int_0^t a(t-s)b(s)ds$, in which the variable 't' is also the upper bound of the integral.

Comment: @booksee You are right, I should read more carefully. But it is essentially the same argument. When computing the convolution you get such a term, too.

Comment: @NikWeaver your modified example is perfect.

Comment: @booksee, the product you mention is still convolution, just of functions supported on $[0, \infty)$ (so that $\int_0^\infty a(t - s)b(s)\mathrm ds$ equals $\int_0^t a(t - s)b(s)\mathrm ds$).

Answer (score 15):

A less explicit answer: Salem and Zygmund proved that convolution $L^1(\mathbb T) \times L^1(\mathbb T) \to L^1(\mathbb T)$ is onto.

This was shown to hold for all locally compact groups by Paul Cohen in 1959. This result was the starting point of an entire industry establishing "factorization theorems".

A nice survey on this topic is Jan Kisynski, [On Cohen's proof of the Factorization Theorem](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl:80/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-apmv75z2p177bwm), Annales Polonici Mathematici 75, 2 (2000), 177-192.

Comment: Cool, I did not know this.

Comment: Isn't much of that "industry" subsumed by the Cohen Factorization Theorem for appropriate modules over a Banach algebra?